# Google maps API v3 click IE9

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-9

I use a basic on-click geolocation on my site, and it utilizes map click event to get coordinates. It works nice on Chrome, Firefox etc. and even IE10, but in IE9 or IE10(Compatibility mode 9) click event does not fire (doubleclick zooms the map, but no click). There is a polygon on map, and it catches click event all right (still map click does not work if polygon is removed).I know that IE8 is not supported by APIv3, but IE9 is listed as supported. There are no console errors logged.
Any help or advice is appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/QxB2b/4/

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
var target = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json";
var latLng = e.latLng.lat() + "," + e.latLng.lng();
console.log(latLng); // works here
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: target,
    data: "latlng=" + latLng + "&sensor=false",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(r, status, err) {
        console.log(r);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Problem solved, that was not google maps but IE9 HTTP Request implementation bug. It totally did not send request and so totally did not execute any callback.

There is a solution for this: https://github.com/jaubourg/ajaxHooks/blob/master/src/xdr.js

Comment: You should post an excerpt of your code, or link a jsfiddle to help us to reproduce - and solve - your problem

Comment: Problem solved, see above, thanks to everybody